# What can be used to 'gzip' in Windows?

Tags: windows, gzip

gzipped files are awesome! they are the best compressed files I know, **.rar** and **.zip** are nowhere near , if you compare the compression ratios...

Generally I use Windows, does anyone know how can I **gzip in Windows**??
I have severe limits at the attachment sizes here, so anything that compresses more, is better.

Comment: By the way, gzip generally have lower compression rations than `rar` and `7z` (albeit it de/compresses much faster), and it can only compress single files - generally tarballs when archiving (such as `myfolder.tar.gz` and it's generally suited for servers where you don't want to spend even a tiny bit of extra CPU if not necessary. For archiving I recommend 7z, it has a very good LZMA algorithm. And it's free/open source.

Comment: Compression ratio is not the main rationale for `gzip`, the main advantages are: **1.** it is the **standard of the internet**, standard for [digital_preservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_preservation) and for many serious systems (e.g. Apache Hive default); **2.** it can operate in pipes, in [stream mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_processing), with no disk-usage.  **3.** it is free, transparent, it is **not a black-box**, no risk of Trojans, etc. **4.** the compression ratios and CPU usage are reasonable when compared with other generic compression algorithms.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) will handle gzip format. It also offers lzma compression which is *much* better than gzip.

If you want a command-line gzipper just like gzip in linux, try [this](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm)

Comment: +1, but 7zip has a command line interface too. I use it for automated backups.

Comment: originally used WinRar, but switched to 7zip when I noticed it had shell integration as well. I also use a combinations of bash, nice, ls, xargs, and 7zip to uncompress bzip2 files and recompress them into 7z files on a linux web server (for Team Fortress 2 maps).

Comment: @Powerlord That's cool, really, but WHY are you parsing `ls` directly? It does work most of the time, but you should really be using something like `find`, shouldn't you?

Comment: @Wyatt8740 It was a flat directory structure.  Besides, `ls -1` doesn't need parsing, you can pass it directly to `xargs`.

Comment: @Powerlord so `ls -1` can handle exotic stuff like newlines in filenames?

Answer (score 3):

For those looking to compress multiple files into a `.tar.gz` file *on Windows*:

Since [2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171219-tar-and-curl-come-to-windows), the `tar` ([bsdtar](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&format=html)) utility is available on Windows, both in *PowerShell* and in the basic *Command Prompt* (cmd).

For a summary of options, run `tar --help`, for a detailed list of options, visit the [docs](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&format=html).

For example, to add the contents of `my_directory` to `my.tar.gz` you can do:

```
tar -czf my.tar.gz --directory my_directory *
```

where `-czf` combines the options for "create", "**gzip**", and "filename", respectively. `--directory` (or `-C`) changes directory before adding all content using `*` (or `.`, which also works in *bash*).

To inspect the file's contents:

```
tar -tf my.tar.gz
```

where `-tf` is "list", "filename"

And to extract the content into `some_directory`:

```
tar -xf my.tar.gz --directory=some_directory
```

where `-xf` is "extract", "filename"

For those that have [git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) installed: *git bash* includes both [GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/All-Options.html#All-Options) (as opposed to [bsdtar](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&format=html)) and the [`gzip`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/gzip.html) program.

Comment: `tar -c` stores all the files with the full specified path.  Is this different on the Windows version?

Comment: @OskarSkog you are right, I should have used `--directory` (or `-C`). I've updated the answer accordingly. On Windows, `*` does not exclude hidden files, as far as I know. Alternatively, `.` would also work, but places everyting under `./` in the archive. The end result after extraction is the same, but the `.` may be confusing when inspecting the archive.

Comment: Does this actually work? `tar -czf my.tar.gz --directory my_directory *`  I *believe* the `*` will be turned into filenames before tar moves into the specified directory.  On a unix shell, I would do `(cd my_directory && tar -czf ../my.tar.gz ./*)` to accomplish what your example is trying to do. (Everything in parenthesis is run in a different process so you won't have to cd back)

Comment: @OskarSkog Using bash on linux (ubuntu) the `*` fails, but `.` does work. Using powershell or command prompt on windows (10), both the `*` and `.` work as described above.

Comment: @OskarSkog As for the `-C`, I believe it is "order sensitive", as mentioned in the gnu tar docs [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/All-Options.html#All-Options) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/one.html#directory), and in the [docs for bsdtar](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&format=html#OPTIONS) ([windows appears to use bsdtar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171219-tar-and-curl-come-to-windows))

Answer (score 1):

7zip and zgip are different things. You can't use 7zip to get the profit you want to get from the real gzip.

Try to use binaries from here http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm

Comment: Hi, seems that you was wrong in say *"You can't use 7zip"*, please correct it. The problem is not functional, the problem is **reliability**: non-open is non transparent, is a  black-box. A black-box  can be a trojan, etc. So, **`gzip` is the most reliable**.

Comment: Hum.. Sorry, [original gzip windows distribution](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm) is really old (2007!)  and **ugly for install**. Not friendly... So, not useful for 99% of users.